# nodejs return variable from request

Tags: node.js, variables, express, request

I'm using express.

From a controller, I call a function that makes a request to an URL and retrives a HTML tag (with cheerio). I'm not able to return that value even that all console.logs work.

Code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var data = "none";
    var newData = parse(data);

    console.log(newData);
})



function parse(out){
    {
        url = 'http://www.XXXXXX.int/';
        out =  out || "Init value";
        request(url, out,  function(error, response, html){
            console.log(out);
            out ="ASDA";
            return out; //op1
        }) ;
        return out; //op2
    }

}
```

I'm able to retrive the title var. But the return's (even inside request) return don't modify original's value. It might be something about synchrony.. but i'm really lost..

Any light?¿

Answer (score 3):

Requests are made asynchronously. You need to add a callback, which is standard Node.JS architecture

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var data = "none";
    var newData = "";
    parse(data , function( val ) {
         newData = val;
         console.log( "newData : " , newData );
         console.log( "this happens last" );
         // if you need to return anything, return it here. Do everything else you want to do inside this parse function.
         return res.sendStatus( 200 );
    } );
    console.log( "this happens first" );
});

function parse( out , callback ){
    url = 'http://www.XXXXXX.int/';
    out =  out || "Init value";
    request(url, out,  function(error, response, html){
        // don't you do anything with the error, response, html variables?
        console.log( "out : " , out);
        out ="ASDA";
        return callback( out ); //op1
   }) ;
}
```

Doing that, your output should be:

```
this happens first
out :  none
newData :  ASDA
this happens last
```

Comment: I added the callback, but after the "parse(-.." call, before closing router, if I console.log(newData) it will display 'none'.

Comment: @user1343998 again, this is asynchronous, so anything written after the function with callback will actually be done BEFORE what you have in your callback. Check my answer, I've edited it